# How to do card stacking effect in react-bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5, react-bootstrap

I am looking for a way to make this [card stacking effect](https://codepen.io/william-goldsworthy/pen/JzVajj) in `react-bootstrap`.

I tried following the code in the link but it is quite different that I cannot implement it in react-bootstrap. I want it to be responsive because I use `Container fluid` with `Row` and `Col`.

It does not have to be pure CSS. Javascript usage or a combination of both is acceptable.